# Overloading new operator using friend function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I have overloaded 'new' operator as a member function for my class Array. I need help overloading it as a friend function. See the program below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Array {
    private:
    int *arr;
    int size;

    public:

    void * operator new (size_t size)
    {
        void *ptr = ::new Array;
        return ptr;
    }

    void operator delete(void *ptr)
    {
        ::delete ptr;
    }

    Array(int n=5)
    {
        this->size = n;
        this->arr = new int[n];
    }

    void input()
    {
        cout<<"Enter the values"<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            cin>>arr[i];
    }

    void show()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            cout<<arr[i]<<" ";

        cout<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Array *A = new Array(4);
    A->input();
    A->show();
    return 0;
}
```

What I tried to do in friend function:

```
void * operator new (size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc)
{
   void * ptr = ::new Array;
   return ptr;
}
```

I got an infinite loop for this. Can anyone help me here?

Edit : Grammar

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with your program (as long as you leave the 'new' overload OUT)...well some minor details but it should compile/run.  Why exactly do you want to overload 'new' like this?  Where is this friend function supposed to be?  What are the compiler errors?   Did you trouble shoot the "infinite loop"?  If so then how?  As for the code you claim for your 'friend' function...be aware that the new operator is naturally recursive on all control paths and the way you are using it should cause a run-time stack overflow in spite of probably compiling OK.  A bad idea on a rampage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be only one `::operator new(size_t)`.  Normally the standard library provides one. If you provide one, it *replaces* (doesn't overload) the one provided by the standard library.

Your version calls itself unconditionally (there's no other `::operator new(size_t)`) so there's an unbounded recursion and a stack overflow in there.

You cannot provide `::operator new(size_t)` and hope it will work together with the system-provided `::operator new(size_t)` but only for your class.

The only way to make a global overloaded `operator new` is to give it a different signature, e.g.

```
enum foo {bar};
void* operator new (std::size_t size, foo) { ... }

...

Array* arr = new (bar) Array;
```

But you can use it to allocate any type, not just `Array`, regardless of which classes decide to befriend it.

Answer (score 0):

So just adding on above answer you can overload your operator new and delete in following manner and this will work because one inside constructor will call operator new[] not operator new.Also no need to make this friend since you are not accessing any private data member in this function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Array {
    private:
    int *arr;
    int size;

    public:             
    Array(int n=5)
    {
        this->size = n;
        this->arr = new int[n];
    }
    void input()
    {
        cout<<"Enter the values"<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            cin>>arr[i];
    }
    void show()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            cout<<arr[i]<<" ";

        cout<<endl;
    }
};
void * operator new (size_t size)
{
   void *ptr = std::malloc(size);
   return ptr;
}
void operator delete(void *ptr)
{
   std::free(ptr);
}
int main()
{
    Array *A = new Array(4);
    A->input();
    A->show();
    return 0;
}
```